# Loop for urls and a nice result

Tags: dalekjs

The question is how can i do a loop and how can i have a nice result like
94 Urls are ok and this three are not working.

```
var urls = [
'http://www.testify/page1',
'http://www.testify/page2'
];

module.exports = {
'validate some url': function (test) {
    test.open('http://www.testify/page1')
        .wait(500)
        .assert.title().is.not('Die Seite wurde leider nicht gefunden')
        .assert.url('http://www.testify/page1', 'URL is as expected')
        .assert.numberOfElements('.product').is.gt(0, 'There are more than 0 products')
        .done();
},
};
```

Comment: And the solution is ;)

http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/23817/Screenshot-of-an-array-of-URLs-(DalekJS)

Answer (score 1):

great to see that you found an answer to that question yourself.
In case somebody stumbles upon this question again, this would be the code needed for your initial code snippet:

```
var urls = [
'http://www.testify/page1',
'http://www.testify/page2'
];

module.exports = {
'validate some url': function (test) {

    urls.forEach(function (url) {
      test.open(url)
          .wait(500)
          .assert.title().is.not('Die Seite wurde leider nicht gefunden')
          .assert.url(url, 'URL is as expected')
          .assert.numberOfElements('.product').is.gt(0, 'There are more than 0 products')
    });

    test.done();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {

  'A lot of screenshots': function (test) {
    var resolutions = [{width: 1280, height: 1024}, {width: 1024, height: 768}, {width: 800, height: 600}];
    var pages = ['http://facebook.com', 'http://twitter.com', 'http://dalekjs.com'];

    resolutions.forEach(function (res) {
        pages.forEach(function (page) {
            test.open(page)
                .resize(res)
                .screenshot('pics/' + res.width + '_' + res.height + '_' + page.replace('http://', '') + '.png')
        });
    });

    test.done();
}
}
```